Unable to configure the ArcGIS Server site with the web adaptor (IIS) (11.3)
I have upgraded from ArcGIS Server 10.9.1 to 11.3 on our QA server.
After the upgrade I installed the IIS web adaptor for 11.3, with it's dependencies.
When I want to configure the web adaptor I get the following error message:
Unable to configure the ArcGIS Server site with the web adaptor. Please make sure that the machine hosting the site is running and that the account specified has administrative privileges.


I tried the following thus far with no success:

Gave full access to ArcGIS account on folders C:\arcgisserver and C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server
Reset my password for siteadmin admin account
Added the ip and DNS alias to the etc/hosts file (this worked for 10.9.1 but not for 11.x)

I can access the manager via https://sita-qa-law01.drdlr.gov.za:6443/arcgis/manager
Anything else I could try ?

Please [Edit] the Question to contain the error message as text. Images are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched by others with the same problem.

@P Holtzhausen, have you tried checking these articles? 1. https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/problem-unable-to-configure-arcgis-web-adaptor-iis-with-000031384 2. https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/unable-to-register-the-arcgis-server-with-the-web-adapt-000017734 3. https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/web-adaptor/latest/install/iis/configure-arcgis-web-adaptor-server.htm#:~:text=If%20the%20web%20server%20where%20you%20installed%20ArcGIS%20Web%20Adaptor%20is%20configured%20to%20use%20a%20forward%20proxy%2C%20disable%20it%20while%20registering%20the%20Web%20Adaptor.%20Otherwis

Single machine deployment. Yes, web adaptor is installed on the same machine as server. Web adaptor name is the same, but I also tried a new name. Service account the same, but I also tried a different name. I ran the ArcGIS Enterprise port checker, and got the following results:
ArcGIS Server

6080 is OPEN
6443 is OPEN
4000 is CLOSED
4001 is CLOSED
4002 is CLOSED
4004 is CLOSED
1098 is CLOSED
6006 is CLOSED
6099 is OPEN

Walking through trouble-shooting steps is not a GIS SE forte. You really ought to talk with Esri Tech Support (who have more experience with IIS than is likely here).

Check if your ArcGIS Server is compatible with your IIS version.

I was able to get it to work, but with the following configuration:
ArcGIS Server 11.3
ArcGIS Web Adaptor (IIS) 10.9.1
order of steps are important:
do not uninstall ArcGIS web adaptor 10.9.1
upgrade ArcGIS server 11.3
complete upgrade via https://sita-qa-law01.drdlr.gov.za:6443/arcgis/admin/upgrade
